# How do I start Visual Studio Enterprise by default not Professional

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2019

I have both Professional and Enterprise editions of Visual Studio 2019 installed to their default locations on my machine.  I have a button on my taskbar pointed to the Enterprise edition.  When I start VS from it, it instead pulls up the Professional edition.

The taskbar shortcut points to Enterprise:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

and starts in:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE"

I've verified that Exploring to each and starting from their respctive folder starts the expected version.

Any idea why the taskbar is finding the wrong version and hopefully how to stop it from doing so?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this will help. But I find that when I have done Side by Side Installs of Visual Studio ][1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio-versions-side-by-side?view=vs-2019) I discovered that if I did NOT nickname them, the Start menu would simply list multiple instances of "Visual Studio 2019"
(See image)
[image: Use of Nicknames]

Unfortunately I don't know a way to CHANGE the nickname after you have done an install.  Visual Studio "Professional" and Visual Studio "Enterprise" if I recall just show up as "Visual Studio"  I would look on the start pane then interrogate the shortcut to find it's path, then add the correct one to the task bar.

To fix this, I beleive you would have to un-install then re-install Visual Studio.  The Nickname needs to be set at the same time you specify the install path at Install time.  It's too late to change after you have installed Visual Studio. (Although Kudos to anyone who knows the registry hack/other technique to fix it.)
In my case I set the revision as the nickname.  The "()" parands are supplied by Microsoft... don't add them.  Thats how I learned you have to uninstall-reinstall to change a nickname.